# Aspect ratio responsive Youtube video inside a flexbox

Tags: css, iframe, flexbox

```css
.d1 {
  background-color: #f1f2f4;
  display: flex;
  padding: 4%;
}

.video-container {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  height: 0;
}

.video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.d1>.text {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Vbg81kc56FU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

I use a `flexbox` that consists of a left and right part, both of equal width. On the left, I am trying to insert a youtube video that should be responsive but, from my attempts, it does not keep its aspect ratio but appears to have more height. How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove the WIDTH and HEIGHT attributes from the iframe element.

Comment: Same results...

Comment: @darkchampionz which section you get more `height`. Is `.video-container` or `.text`?

Comment: Updated my answer... Might get you a bit closer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with extra wrapper. like below

```css
.d1 {
  background-color: #f1f2f4;
  display: flex;
  padding: 4%;
}

.video-container {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.video-container div {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
}

.video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="video-container">
    <div>
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Vbg81kc56FU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k965grx0/)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sorry, didn't read your question very well:

This approach seems to be working a bit better:
https://codepen.io/lokase/pen/JjGxpEJ

```css
.d1 {
  background-color: #f1f2f4;
  display: flex;
  padding: 4%;
}

.video-container {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  height: 0;
}

.video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
}

.text {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Vbg81kc56FU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This indeed works but it seems to leave an empty space at the bottom of the video. If you add for example a `background-color: red;` in `.video-container` you will see what I mean =<